# Sumar naturales hasta "n"

Tags: python, algoritmos

Deseo implementar una función `def suma_naturales_hasta(n)`.

Para ello podría utilizar un bucle `for` que me recorriera el numero que he introducido, es decir, si pongo 3, que la suma sea 1+2+3.

¿Cómo podría implementar este `for`? ¿Debería usar la función `range()`?

Comment: [Te he votado negativamente porque no intentaste nada](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2874/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haciendolo con un `for` podría ser así:

```
def suma_naturales_hasta(n):
    total=0
    for i in range(1,n+1): # se pone n+1 para que incluya este último
        total+=i
    print total

suma_naturales_hasta(5) #15
suma_naturales_hasta(4) #10
```

Comment: [Te he votado negativamente porque es solamente código.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2882/)

Answer (score 0):

podrias hacerlo asi

```
 ###Calcular e imprimir la suma 1+2+3+4+5+...+50
    h = range(1, 51)
    print sum(h) #con el comando sum se suma los numeros de una lista
```

Comment: [Te he votado negativamente porque es solamente código.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2882/)

Comment: @gbianchi el código está comentado explicando qué es lo que hace cada línea.

Answer (score 0):

Debes sumar 1 para incluir el último número:

```
def suma_naturales_hasta(n):
    return sum(range(n+1)) # sumar 1 para incluir el último número
```

Y ya funciona:

> >>> suma_naturales(5)
>   15

Comment: [Te he votado negativamente porque es solamente código.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2882/)